# Displaying a custom button on camera view

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Does anyone know if there's a way to stick a custom button on the camera view to allow a user to select a photo from their library like oink or instagram does without making a custom view? Thanks!

Edit

Adding the button seems easy with the overlay; does anyone know how to actually display the photo library from there and use what the person selects?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation for UIImagePickerController:

> You can customize an image picker controller to manage user
>   interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing
>   the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in
>   “Capturing Still Images or Movies.” **You can display your custom
>   overlay view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls.**
>   Custom overlay views for the UIImagePickerController class are
>   available in iOS 3.1 and later by way of the cameraOverlayView
>   property. For a code example, see the PhotoPicker sample code project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

The delegate you choose for your photo library button should also have access to the UIImagePickerController.  Then, when the button is pressed for photo album, you can call presentModalViewController:animated: (or presentViewController:animated:completion: if you are targeting iOS 5 and up) on the UIImagePickerController, passing in a new UIImagePickerController with sourceType set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary.

I've handled this issue in two other ways: 1st, just use a UIActionSheet to prompt the user prior to showing the image picker; 2nd, host the pickers in a tab controller or other container controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That will allow me to add the button to there, what about displaying the photo library selection after that? Have you done this before? Thanks!