# How to add floating button in iOS camera?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using UIImagePickerController for my camera and have added an Overlay View Controller to take snaps and go to the allbum(as explained in PhotoPicker example).
But now I want to add two floating buttons as in normal camera (one for flash and and another to switch the camera).
Can you please tell how to add those floating buttons or what are they exactly called if not floating buttons?
Thnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220872/displaying-a-custom-button-on-camera-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `UIButtons` programmatically and then add them to the `Overlay View Controller` by using `[overlayView addSubView:yourButton];`

Comment: Thnx, I am able to add the button but cannot Press it. Can you suggest how to make it pressable ?

Comment: `[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Hi Fernando, even adding an action for doesn't seem to make it pressable. I can see the Button but touch event goes to Camera screen instead of the button. I even tried making the button becomeFirstResponder; but that doesn't work. Thnx

Comment: Ok, got it working; I had to add the button to the imagePickerController rather than to the overlayView. Now its working.  Thanks for all the help.